# python using data from a list, where by you call the data from its index number

Tags: python, list, select, indexing

I must open a file, compute the averages of a row and column and then the max of the data sheet. The data is imported from a text file. When I am done with the program, it should look like an excel sheet, only printed on my terminal.

Data file must be seven across by six down.
88 90 94 98 100 110 120
75 77 80 86 94 103 113
80 83 85 94 111 111 121
68 71 76 85 96 122 125
77 84 91 102 105 112 119
81 85 90 96 102 109 134

Later, I will have to print the above data. I the math is easy, my problem is selecting the number from the indexed list. Ex:
selecting index 0, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40. Which should be numbers 88, 75, 80, 68, 77, 81.

What I get when I input the index number is 0 = 8, 1 = 8, 2 = " "... ect.

What have I done wrong here? I have another problem where I had typed into the program the list, which works as I wanted this to work. That program was using the index numbers to select a month. 0= a blank index, 1 = january, 2 = Febuary, ect...

I hope this example made clear what I intended to do, but cannot seem to do. Again, the only difference between my months program and this program is that for the below code, I open a file to fill the list. Have I loaded the data poorly? Split and stripped the list poorly? Help is more useful than answers, as I can learn rather than be given the answer.

def main():

```
print("Program to output a report of noise for certain model cars.")
print("Written by censored.")
print()
fileName = input("Enter the name of the data file: ")
infile = open(fileName, "r")

infileData = infile.read()
line = infileData
#for line in infile:
list = line.split(',')
list = line.strip("\n")

print(list)

n = eval(input("Enter a index number: ", ))

print("The index is", line[n] + ".")

print("{0:>38}".format(str("Speed (MPH)")))
print("{0:>6}".format(str("Car")), ("{0:>3}".format(str(":"))),
    ("{0:>6}".format(str("30"))), ("{0:>4}".format(str("40"))),
    ("{0:>4}".format(str("50"))))
```

main()

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Use `int()` instead of `eval()` to parse `int`s.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion to replace eval() with int(), that was more an artifact from the month program that I copied for the test of my list indexing. I have implamented this change into my month program. :)

Comment: What is the exact format of your input file? A single line like `88, 90, 94` etc.? Or is it `88,`, `90,`, etc. on separate lines?

Comment: So just a single line with entries separated by spaces?

Comment: no, the data file isn't copying into this properly. The data file is seven digits across: 88 90 94 98 100 110 120 then a return and the next line of data.

Comment: not sure if matters, but 'list' is a built-in type.  as in isinstance([], list).  it can't be too good to clobber it.  from the description of what you are getting, it looks as if what you think is a list is a string instead.  in python, it can be sometimes tricky to differentiate lists from strings, they both have indices, for loop, lengths...  try print type(list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep overwriting your variables, and I wouldn't recommend masking a built-in (`list`).

```
infileData = infile.read()
line = infileData
#for line in infile:
list = line.split(',')
list = line.strip("\n")
```

should be:

```
infileData = list(map(int, infile.read().strip().split()))
```

This reads the file contents into a string, strips off the leading and trailing whitespace, splits it up into a list separated by whitespace, maps each element as an `int`, and creates a `list` out of that.

Or:

```
stringData = infile.read()
stringData = stringData.strip()
stringData = stringData.split()

infileData = []

for item in stringData:
    infileData.append(int(item))
```

Storing each element as an integer lets you easily do calculations on it, such as `if item > 65` or `exceed = item - 65`. When you want to treat them as strings, such as for printing, cast them as such with `str()`:

```
print("The index is", str(infileData[n]) + ".")
```

Comment: Thank you for this line of code I would love to use if allowed to but my instructor will not accept any such lines of code. I will have to break that down into a multi line formate.

When I used your code, I received the following error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Projects\Noise\noise.py", line 48, in <mo
    main()
  File "C:\Python34\Projects\Noise\noise.py", line 31, in mai
    print("The index is", infileData[n] + ".")
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: The problem with that is not in my code, it's with the `print` call. Use `str(infileData[n])` instead of just `infileData[n]`. I'll add an expanded version of the code.

Comment: Thank you for your help, now to figure out how to break up the code into multiple lines... An annoying thing about my instructor, otherwise he's a great guy.

Comment: I thank you for all of your help, it is very appreciated. If I had the rep to upvote your answer to a +1, I would.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, it looks like your data is space-separated not comma separated. So when you call,

```
list = line.split(',')
```

the list looks like this,

```
['88 90 94 98 100 110 120 75 77 80 86 94 103 113 80 83 85 94 111 111 121 68 71 76 85 96 122 125 77 84 91 102 105 112 119 81 85 90 96 102 109 134']
```

So therefore, when you access list[0], you will get '8' not '88', or when you access list[2] you will get ' ', not '94'

```
list = line.split() # this is what you should call (space-separated)
```

Again this answer is based on how your data is presented.

Comment: in your above statement, and from the code, list[0] would the whole '88.....134' string and list[2] would give an IndexError.